# custom exception handler for DRF response and Django response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to define a custom exception class and raise it.

Django rest framework has a hook where I can define custom exception handler,

(http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)

Django also provides a way to do it via middleware.

Question: If I want to handle exceptions in drf views and regular django views, would it be sufficient to handle them in django middleware?

Or do I need separate handler for DRF views?

In other words, does DRF request/response goes through django middleware as well or not?

Comment: All DRF views are also just Django views. So if you write a Django middleware, it will intercept every single request that comes in. 

To answer the question, yes it's sufficient to just write a Django middleware if that middleware will return a HTTPResponse of some sort.

Comment: In one of our microservices that communicates only via APIs, we use rest framework as our last level of abstraction. So its easier to use the DRF exception handler. 

The drf request/response goes through the django middleware also. It's the outermost abstraction layer for these objects in Django.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script called `exception_middleware.py` anywhere in the project directory (preferably in the main app directory) and add the following:

```
import logging
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings

logger = logging.getLogger("StackDriverHandler")


class ExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if settings.DEBUG:
            host = "http"
        else:
            # TODO: set for https
            host = "http"

        if response.status_code == 500:
            return render(request, "error_templates/500.html")

        if response.status_code == 404:
            return render(request, "error_templates/404.html")

        if response.status_code == 403:
            return render(request, "error_templates/403.html")

        return response
   def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        try:
            logger.info(request, extra=exception)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(exception)
        return None
   def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        try:
            logger.info(request, extra=exception)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(exception)
        return None
```

Add the path to this class in the MIDDLEWARE section in the settings.py file of your Django project (at the last).

That's it. This middleware will get executed during each of your requests and will check if you are in DEBUG and if there is an exception, this middleware will then create a message for you :) .