# django rest framework custom exception handling doesn't return expected error code

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement a custom error handling in a project using django rest framework, and I want it to return a json when attempting to create a new user but the email is already used (I am enforcing the uniqueness of the email). I want to return an error code 400 and the resulting json to be like this:

```
{
    "email": [
        "eMAil already in use."
    ]
}
```

I implemented a solution proposed in https://medium.com/@mwhitt.w/restful-error-messages-with-django-537047892dff, but I get a 500 error code and no json back.

This is my `customexception.py`

```
class BaseCustomException(Exception):
    status_code = None
    error_message = None
    is_an_error_response = True

    def __init__(self, error_message):
        Exception.__init__(self, error_message)
        self.error_message = error_message

    def to_dict(self):
        return {'errorMessage':self.error_message}

class ExistingEmailException(BaseCustomException):
    status_code = 400

    def __init__(self):
        BaseCustomException.__init__(self, 'eMail already in use')
```

This is my `middleware.py`:

```
import traceback
from django.http import JsonResponse

def is_registered(exception):
    try:
        return exception.is_an_error_response
    except AttributeError:
        return False

class RequestExceptionHandler:
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if is_registered(exception):
            status = exception.status_code
            exception_dict = exception.to_dict()
        else:
            status = 500
            exception_dict = {'errorMessage':'Unexpected Error!'}

        error_message = exception_dict['errorMessage']
        traceback.print_exc()
        return JsonResponse(exception_dict, status=status)
```

This is my serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            user = models.User.objects.get(email=validated_data.get('email'))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = models.User.objects.create(**validated_data)

            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            Token.objects.create(user=user)

            return user
        else:
            raise ExistingEmailException()
```

And this is the result I get:

```
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/Intellibook/UsersManagerApp/serializers.py", line 27, in create
    raise ExistingEmailException()
GeneralApp.customexceptions.ExistingEmailException: eMail already in use
[06/Jun/2018 17:12:20] "POST /es/users_manager/users/ HTTP/1.1" 500 102163
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are getting an unexpected error code is that the example you are following is not designed for use with django-rest-framework.  While it should in theory be possible to use django's middleware to hijack the response (I'm looking at the first comment in response to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44303780/2715819)), the simplest and in my opinion best approach would be to follow [the DRF manual on custom exceptions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling).